# Python3 download document from web

Tags: python-3.x, download, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

I am new in Python3 and I am trying to download a doc after login to a website.

I have 2 url which can let me instantly login to the page and download the doc. after login which are:

1. https://www.xxxcompany.com/login.action?loginname=name&password=psw
2. https://www.xxxcompany.com/doc_download_all.action?ID=37887&edition=PD&Year=2018&Month=10&Day=5&&CLI=&transferNumber=&inOut=C&deviceType=A&minDuration=0&maxDuration=0&sortType=0&sortAsc=1&showAdv=0&viewtype=0&subPage=M&RMID=-1&updateRMID=&updateRecordID=&customField1=

Here is my code. Its definitely not work and it doesn't print me the status code. Did I misunderstand some concept? Please hep me to solve the problem. Thank you so much!

```
from lxml import html
import webbrowser
import requests
def login():
        with requests.session() as s:
        # fetch the login page
                s.get(url1)
                print(s.status_code) #check whether its successfully login
                s.get(url2) #download the doc
```

Comment: If it is your full download code. You should write data to file after you got data. Because dont know if it is full code , so i can do is add a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write data to file.

```
url = "http://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xxxx/sample.doc"
import requests
with requests.Session() as se:
    req = se.get(url)
    with open(url.split("/")[-1],"wb") as doc:
        doc.write(req.content)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if the download file is actually a zip file? In the browser, I have to input the first url to do auto-login and input second url to auto-download the file. Can I use the method you mention above?

Comment: of course you can. If you want to unpack zip file , use [`ziplib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html) @WILLIAM